# undo function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This does not strictly have an undo button, but the fucntion i have grays out and crosses out an item on click. When clicked again, I want the gray and cross-out to return to normal (black and not crossed). https://codepen.io/HelleFl/pen/OjNQop

```
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  $(this).css("color", "gray");      
  if ($(this).css('color', 'gray') {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'black');
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
      })
   });
```

I can't seem to figure it out, and codepen tells me to check the semicolons.

Comment: Don't do this.  Don't nest a binding inside another binding.  Instead perform a conditional in the top level binding.  Also making the style change a class that can be added/removed greatly reduces the scope of the issue.

Comment: could you elaborate on that some more, please? So instead of nesting the UNDO function inside the function to DO, separate the IF function completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('grayStrike');
});


//or without a class


$(".item2").click(function() {
  if ($(this).css('text-decoration').split(' ')[0] !== "line-through") {
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    $(this).css("color", "gray");
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', '');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', '');
  }
});


//delegate version so if new items are created, it doesn't matter

$(document).on('click', ".item3", function() {
  if ($(this).css('text-decoration').split(' ')[0] !== "line-through") {
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    $(this).css("color", "gray");
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', '');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', '');
  }
});
```

```css
.item.grayStrike {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">test</div>
<hr>
<div class="item2">test1</div>
<div class="item2">test2</div>
<div class="item2">test3</div>
<div class="item2">test4</div>
<div class="item2">test5</div>
<div class="item2">test6</div>
<div class="item2">test7</div>
<div class="item2">test8</div>
<hr>
<div class="item3">test1</div>
<div class="item3">test2</div>
<div class="item3">test3</div>
<div class="item3">test4</div>
<div class="item3">test5</div>
<div class="item3">test6</div>
<div class="item3">test7</div>
<div class="item3">test8</div>
```

Otherwise if you don't want to use a class.

Comment: I figured out a solution. Thanks to @lekens to get me there.

Comment: @Helle added more divs.  works fine for all of them.

Comment: @Hellie updated with a delegate version.  If you are dynamically creating elements, then the new elements would not have the bindings on them.  So you have to use a delegate so it doesn't matter when they are created, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".item").click(function() {
      $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
      $(this).css("color", "gray");      
      if ($(this).css('color', 'gray')) {
      //  $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).css('color', 'black');
          $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
           }else{
           $(this).css('color', 'gray');
          $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');}
         // })
       });
```

Comment: when taking out the comment, this code does not execute properly. Maybe missing () {} ?

Comment: A mistake... Try now

Comment: This still does not work. Just copy and paste your code into my codepen and see for yourself (and me lol). There seems to be an issue with the parenthesis

Answer (score -1):

A working solution:

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  if ($(this).css("text-decoration").split(" ")[0] !== "line-through") {
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    $(this).css("color", "gray");
  } else {
    $(this).css("color", "");
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "");
  }
});
```

Comment: Again, don't nest bindings. With this logic ever 2n+1 clicks you are going to be adding another click binding on the element that is unnecessary.  I updated my answer to include a non class, non double binding version.

Comment: @Taplar This does not work. When clicked on, it grays out. When clicked again, nothing happens

Comment: @taplar The version as it is posted has an incorrect number of closing tags, hence gives an error in codepen. When corrected to the right number, the function does not undo the gray & cross-out

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: @Taplar This edit works once. If i want to gray out and un-gray the item multiple times, the script stops working.

Comment: Works multiple times here on S.O. in that Run code snipplet for me.

Comment: @Taplar This only works for the second items and up, not for the first entry created. Sorry for the lengthy discussion, i am a noob

Comment: I only did item2 so that both the logic could exist in the answer independent of each other.  If you only have the latter, you just have to change the selector back to 'item', not change all your markup

Comment: What?  What do you mean uneven item number?  Possibly update your question with what you are working with now so we can see it.

Comment: @Tapler if you check out the current codepen, I am using your code above *without* a class. I am adding 5 items to the list, i click them, but only items 1,3,5 are gray-able. the rest stays black and not-crossed out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151005/discussion-between-helle-and-taplar).

Comment: You are dynamically creating elements man.  The binding will not exist on them.